# Is it safe to connect external USB 2.0 hard drive to laptop via USB to USB-C adapter

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, adapter, usb-c, usb-network-adapter

My *Lenovo P15 Gen 1* laptop has 3 USB-C connectors:

1. A single *USB-C (3.2 Gen 1)* connector
2. Two *Thunderbolt™ 3 (USB-C)* connectors

Is it safe to connect "standard" USB-2/3 external hard drives (or for the matter of fact – any other USB-2/3 device) via a simple *USB to USB-C adapter* to either one of those ports?
All the external hard disks I own are *micro USB to USB Type A*.

It's just that I've had bad experience with connecting several external hard disks via non-externally-powered USB hubs -- which sometimes cause actual damage to the drives.

Exact connectors' specs, from the laptop's [user guide](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p15_t15g_gen1_ug_en.pdf):

[image]
[image]

The actual USB to USB-C converter I intended to use:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need an adapter?

Comment: @harrymc the cables that came with the external hard drives - are standard USB cables. You mean why I don't buy a new USB-C cable?

Comment: @harrymc - Because a USB 3.0 HDD unlikely is going to have Type-C connector but a Type-A 2.0/3.0

Comment: @golosovsky - Type-C is considered to be a "standard" USB cable, so you have to be specific, one what type of connector the cable is.

Comment: @Ramhound which one of the cables you mean? All the external hard disks I own are micro USB to USB Type A

Comment: If your disks are USB-A, I don't see a reason that this won't work. Just use a good-quality adapter.

Comment: @harrymc The two USB-C connector types I have on the laptop are different. Is it ok to connect to either of them?

Comment: You mean that one is real USB-C and the other is Thunderbolt? I have no experience with Thunderbolt, but the voltage is the same and the difference is only in 1.5A vs 3A. You can't "push" too much power to a device - it will take just as much as it needs (in theory).

Comment: @harrymc Yes. That's the reason I'm asking. It's just that due to my bad experience with USB hubs (which should in theory act just as "splitters") actually damaging external hard drives - I want to be sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: Nobody can guarantee that no harm will come when several devices and cables are joined. How can we know if one is defective?

Comment: @golosovsky - You can safely plug in a Type-C to USB-A adapter into a USB Type-C port.  A Thunderbolt 3 is a different story.

Comment: Adapters like your are [recommended](https://www.macworld.com/article/229045/thunderbolt-3-adapter-m1-imac-macbook-pro-mac-mini-usb-displayp) for Thunderbolt USB-C. In principle, this should work. There are no guarantees for anything, but there's a close to zero chance of anything going wrong. So go ahead, just keep your eyes open.

Comment: @harrymc As you can see in the comment above yours - Ramhound states that connecting a USB-compatible device to a Thunderbolt connector (via Micro-B USB 3.0 to USB-C cable) isn't supported. I'm trying to understand - does the Thunderbolt connectors can be used just as USB-C connectors?

Comment: @Ramhound so, if I'm using a Micro-B USB 3.0 to USB-C cable, for the external hard drive, I can only connect it to the USB-C connector, not to the Thunderbolt connectors?

Comment: @golosovsky: If it's unsupported, why does Apple make a [cable](https://www.amazon.com/Apple-USB-C-to-USB-Adapter/dp/B00VU2OID2?th=1) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be safe to connect a USB-A device to a USB-C port, even if it is a port that supports Thunderbolt.  The Thunderbolt specification requires all hosts with a Thunderbolt USB-C port to be backward compatible with USB 3.x and USB 2.0.  There should be no damage from this.  It sounds like you experienced damage to devices before because of devices that were not up to spec.  Personally, if I planned to use a drive with a micro-B port often with a host that had USB-C then I'd invest in a USB-C to micro-B cable for a solid connection.  These are not terribly expensive and should be available off the shelf at most any place that sells electronics.

Not an endorsement but just an example, I see this cable is available off the shelf at a Best Buy near me.
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/tripp-lite-3-micro-usb-to-usb-type-c-cable-black/6413080.p?skuId=6413080

I've heard of USB hubs that will violate the spec by reporting they are self powered when they are not.  This gives permission for the devices attached to the hub to draw full power, relying on the host to provide the power even though it was not designed to do so.  This can mean the voltage drops, and bad things happen.  So don't buy cheap hardware.  If the price s too good to be true then it likely is.

I hate how USB is getting a bad name because so many products fail to follow the spec.  Buy hardware from trustworthy sources and you should not see hardware get damaged.

Comment: Thank you for the highly detailed explanation.